# Combining Dataframes , duplicating row data

Tags: python, dataframe, merge

[image of dataframes and result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mTUIC.png)

I am looking to merge 2 dataframes based on the ID column. DF2 (on the right) has duplicate ID. I wanted to copy the row data for each case from DF1 for each row of DF2 to get the 'Result' dataframe

Comment: Please, paste the exact code that you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try something like :

```
# Makes sample data
dataA= np.array([2,2,1])
dataB = np.array([4,4,0])
ID = np.array(['Alice','Bob','Charlie'])
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ID, 'dataA': dataA, 'dataB':dataB})
df1

# Makes sample data
dataD= np.array([3,3,4])
dataC = np.array([3,3,4])
ID = np.array(['Alice','Bob','Charlie'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ID, 'dataD': dataD, 'dataC': dataC})

resultdf = pd.merge(df1,df2, on="ID")
resultdf
```